# Visual studio 2019 16.11.4 crashes in options

Tags: visual-studio, crash, ide

After updating from 16.11.3 to 16.11.4, every project in Xamarin makes Visual Studio to close.
I discovered that even running Visual studio without a project, opening options and clicking Xamarin makes IDE to crash.

I found Xamarin log:

> Xamarin Information: 0 : Xamarin - 16.11.000.190-d16-11+2391ed9:
> 10.06.2021 06:27:17Z
> DateTime=2021-10-06T06:27:17.0781098Z: 10.06.2021 06:27:17Z Xamarin Information: 0 : !Xamarin - 16.11.000.190-d16-11+2391ed9:
> 10.06.2021 06:27:17Z
> DateTime=2021-10-06T06:27:17.0781098Z: 10.06.2021 06:27:17Z Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.XamarinAndroidPackage Warning: 0 :
> Initializing Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.XamarinAndroidPackage:
> 10.06.2021 06:27:17Z
> DateTime=2021-10-06T06:27:17.1201193Z: 10.06.2021 06:27:17Z Xamarin.VisualStudio.UnhandledExceptionsManager Error: 0 : An
> unhandled error occurred. Details: Unknown property key for value
> list directories in which to look for classes!
> System.InvalidOperationException: Unknown property key for value
> list directories in which to look for classes!    at
> Xamarin.Android.Tools.JdkInfo.<>c__DisplayClass46_0.b__0(Object
> o, DataReceivedEventArgs e) in
> C:\A\1\14\s\External\androidtools\external\xamarin-android-tools\src\Xamarin.Android.Tools.AndroidSdk\JdkInfo.cs:line
> 263    at System.Diagnostics.Process.ErrorReadNotifyUser(String data)
> at System.Diagnostics.AsyncStreamReader.FlushMessageQueue()    at
> System.Diagnostics.AsyncStreamReader.GetLinesFromStringBuilder()    at
> System.Diagnostics.AsyncStreamReader.ReadBuffer(IAsyncResult ar)    at
> System.IO.Stream.ReadWriteTask.InvokeAsyncCallback(Object
> completedTask)    at
> System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
> executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
> preserveSyncCtx)    at
> System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
> executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
> preserveSyncCtx)    at
> System.IO.Stream.ReadWriteTask.System.Threading.Tasks.ITaskCompletionAction.Invoke(Task
> completingTask)    at
> System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()    at
> System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishStageThree()    at
> System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishStageTwo()    at
> System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Finish(Boolean bUserDelegateExecuted)
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task&
> currentTaskSlot)    at
> System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry(Boolean
> bPreventDoubleExecution)    at
> System.Threading.Tasks.Task.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
> at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()    at
> System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback():
> 10.06.2021 06:27:17Z
> DateTime=2021-10-06T06:27:17.5652083Z: 10.06.2021 06:27:17Z

Please advice. I reinstalled VS and the same...